# Substitute all integers in a range of first 3 characters

Tags: linux, loops, awk, sed

I have a list of IDs in the file `example` shown below:

```
3SN0P00000026941
14N0P00000026677
6SN0P00000024671
3SN0P00000018643
```

What I want to output is shown below:

```
ENSN0P00000026941 3
ENSN0P00000026677 14
ENSN0P00000024671 6
ENSN0P00000018643 3
```

It basically extracts all the integers from the range of the first 3 characters in each row and replaces them with "ENS" or "EN"  respectively. For example, if there is 1 integer in the first 3 characters, it will replace with "EN"; If there are 2 integers, replace with "ENS".

The problem is I do not know how to perform such a substitution that only targets integers in the range of the first 3 characters, and replace them with "EN" or "ENS" based on the number of integers present. My try is using `sed`, `sed 's/^.../ENS/g'`, and the output has no difference compared to the original list.

Any codes or scripts can perform such a process? Such as using `awk`, `sed` or other functions?

Comment: can you have inputs where there are `0` or `3` integers in the first 3 characters?

Comment: will the integers always be at the front of those first 3 characters? or could the first 3 characters have a format like: `<number><letter><number>` or `<letter><letter><number>` or `<letter><number><letter>`?

Comment: @markp-fuso the format of the first 3 characters must be always either <number>SN or <number><number>N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/^([0-9]{1,2})S?(.*)/ENS\2 \1/' input_file
ENSN0P00000026941 3
ENSN0P00000026677 14
ENSN0P00000024671 6
ENSN0P00000018643 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
3SN0P00000026941
14N0P00000026677
6SN0P00000024671
3SN0P00000018643
```

then

```
awk '{two=/^[0-9][0-9]/;print (two?"ENS":"EN") substr($0,two?3:2) " " substr($0,1,two?2:1)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ENSN0P00000026941 3
ENSN0P00000026677 14
ENSN0P00000024671 6
ENSN0P00000018643 3
```

Explanation: I set `two` to `1` if there are at least 2 leading digits, otherwise it is `0`. Then I `print` depending on that value by using so-called ternary operator (condition`:`valueiftrue`?`valueiffalse) and [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, what is printed is concatenation of following elements

- `ENS` if two else `EN`
- part of line starting at 3rd character if two else starting at 2nd character
- space character
- 1st two characters if two else 1st one character

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: this is how you can tell `"Daweo"` is a `ChatGPT`-like bot, since no one actually says `"… else 1st one character"` when transcribing the ternary in `substr($0,1,two?2:1)` to plain english

Answer (score 0):

4 different ways of achieving the same effect :

> ```
>  mawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $!($++NF += $+_))_'
>  gawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $+_^($++NF += $!_))_'
>  nawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_*($++NF += $-_)))_'
>  mawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_~($++NF = +$+_)))^_'
> ```

```
ENSN0P00000026941 3
ENSN0P00000026677 14
ENSN0P00000024671 6
ENSN0P00000018643 3
```

….. and tested across `awk` combinations ::

```
   for ___ in nawk mawk1 mawk2 gawk; do 
   for  __ in 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $!($++NF += $+_))_'
              'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $+_^($++NF += $!_))_'
              'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_*($++NF += $-_)))_'  
              'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_~($++NF = +$+_)))^_'; do 

       echo "$___ '$__'  ::::\f\f\r$( 

       echo '3SN0P00000026941
             14N0P00000026677
             6SN0P00000024671
             3SN0P00000018643' | $( printf '%s' "$___" ) "$__" | gcat -b )\n"
   done 
   done
```

> 

```
nawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $!($++NF += $+_))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

nawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $+_^($++NF += $!_))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

nawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_*($++NF += $-_)))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

nawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_~($++NF = +$+_)))^_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

mawk1 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $!($++NF += $+_))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

mawk1 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $+_^($++NF += $!_))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

mawk1 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_*($++NF += $-_)))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

mawk1 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_~($++NF = +$+_)))^_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

mawk2 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $!($++NF += $+_))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

mawk2 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $+_^($++NF += $!_))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

mawk2 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_*($++NF += $-_)))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

mawk2 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_~($++NF = +$+_)))^_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

gawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $!($++NF += $+_))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

gawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $+_^($++NF += $!_))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

gawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_*($++NF += $-_)))_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3

gawk 'sub("^[^N]+", "ENS", $(_~($++NF = +$+_)))^_'  ::::

     1  ENSN0P00000026941 3
     2  ENSN0P00000026677 14
     3  ENSN0P00000024671 6
     4  ENSN0P00000018643 3
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code.

```
awk '
match($0,/^([0-9]{0,3})(.*)$/,arr){
  if(length(arr[1])==1){
    $0="E" arr[2]
  }
  if(length(arr[1])==2){
    $0="EN" arr[2]
  }
  if(length(arr[1])==3){
    $0="ENS" arr[2]
  }
  print $0,arr[1]
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: your code outputs `ENN0P00000026677 14` for line 2 of `OP`'s sample instead of `ENS`